# How to calculate upward force of a container filled with a less dense gas than the surroundings where it is placed?

Tags: forces, density, buoyancy

I'm trying to determine the calculation which would state the upward force of a container where the density inside the container is less then that in which it sits.

Does this calculation change with shape? I.e. sphere vs cube?

Comment: I think you are looking for [Archimedes' principle](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedes'_principle).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resultant upward force= upthrust-weight

1. Upthrust= volume of container* density of surrounding medium*9.81

Thus, the formula for the volume will change according to the shape of the container

2.weight=density inside container*volume of container*9.81

If the upthrust is more than the weight of the object, the object moves upwards